# Two products, two prices, one page

Tags: magento2, attributes, pricing

I'm currently in the process of moving my website to Magento (and I'm new to it -- my apologies.)

On our current site we offer two or more formats of the same book at different prices.

Book A might be $18 for the paperback and $45 for the hardcover

Book B might be $20 for the paperback and $30 for the hardcover.

It's not an attribute add-on where I could add $10 to the paperback to get the price of the hardcover. I've found that absolute pricing works best.

So my questions:

1. Should the hardcover and paperback be the same SKU?
2. How do I identify the two prices for the two formats? I'm assuming it's attribute pricing, but I've not yet found a way to do it.
3. Can the two formats share one product page?

Thanks so much!!

Jeff

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is [Custom Product Options](https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-options-custom.html). We use this on our site to avoid having to set up multiple products when in reality it's the same product with different "options".

Comment: Thank you. I saw this, but I don't think it quite fits. The hardcover will have its own SKU as will the paperback. Additionally, I will definitely need to keep track of inventory for the books in-stock. 

But this is close to what I want!